command 'github.copilot.signin' not found
I'm having trouble with github copilot vscode extension.
I recently reinstalled Pop OS on my desktop, and before that, Copilot worked fine. but since then I can't use it. I try reinstalling the extension and even the VScode itself. I even try different versions and sources for vscode (apt and snapd). still nothing.
note that i'm able to login and sync my github profile
enter image description here
